# HTML autocomplete is not working along with Django extension in VSCode

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, django-extensions

I am currently using the latest version of VSCode and Django. Whenever I enable the Django extension by Baptiste Darthenay, HTML autocomplete stops working. If I disable the Django extension and reload VSCode, it will start to work again. What should I do to make the HTML autocomplete work along with the Django extension?

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete as in Emmet? (ex. typing `.my-class` creating a div with that class?).

Comment: What I am talking about is the most basic autocomplete i.e. type `h1` and it will suggest an autocomplete for h1 header.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try adding this to your settings.json file:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html",
    "jinja-html": "html"
}
```

Additionally you can also add this one and tweak it to your preferences:

```
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": true,
        "other": true,
        "strings": true
    },
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on"
}
```

Comment: Just imputing the top code enables the autocomplete but only if you don't begin your tags with "<". Just typing "p" or "div" and clicking tab will auto-complete.
Also `"django-html": "html"` seems like it is enough. Could you tell me what the second line does as I didn't notice anything different with Jinjas auto-completion. :)

Answer (score 14):

Try the below solution which worked for me:

1. With your VSCode open to your Django project.
2. Open an HTML file (e.g within your templates folder)
3. At the bottom right of the VSCode screen you will see 'Django HTML'
4. Click on that, which then takes you to a language selection screen
5. Type HTML and click
6. You will notice the prompt at the bottom right will now change to 'HTML'
7. You should now have autocomplete for HTML working well

Comment: work for me as well !

Answer (score 5):

For those who can't find settings.json, you can just go to **Settings>Extensions>Emmet>Include Languages**. Then, click on **Add Item** and fill in:

```
key: django-html
value: html
```

Answer (score 2):

Django template language syntax highlighting in `html` !

No need to switch to `django-html` !

Use this extension : [Django Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=almahdi.code-django) (zero config)

Answer (score 1):

Only by adding `"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}` in `settings.json` fixed the problem you mentioned.

Before:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
"liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
},
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"grunt.autoDetect": "on",
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "django-html"
},

"[django-html]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
    }
}
```

}

After:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
"liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
},
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"grunt.autoDetect": "on",
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "django-html"
},

"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},

"[django-html]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
    }
}
```

}

You can see the discussion here: https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django/issues/16

Comment: Please maintain `indentation`  in your answer, i am reviewer.