# Disable Shortcut: Conflicts of boilerplate with Django extension in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, django, vscode-extensions, shortcut, django-extensions

Tell me why we are unable to use boilerplate (!) shortcut in vs code to add html while having Django extension installed its creating conflict it disables shortcut to add html. I have to add html code manually why its happening tell me the reason and solution that I can use both on same time without any conflict and disabling. As I am a beginner in Django please do guide me.[in this image you can clearly see that after installing the extension this shortcut is not generating boilerplate after pressing enter key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1iwZ.jpg)

I tried to change extensions settings but unable to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML autocomplete is not working along with Django extension in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66173731/html-autocomplete-is-not-working-along-with-django-extension-in-vscode)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)